# Database Field Index vs Hard coded Index - which is better?

Tags: database, indexing, odoo

I was Asked to develop an indexing class for my claim module on odoo(ex openerp) this class will index the claims topic field (string field).I'm advancing a little by little and if you want I'll gladly share my simple solution with you. But a question keeps nagging me over and over. Does this class worth it ? I read on some article that hard coded indexing class can be better than creating directly an index on the needed column.

```
def index_text_file(topic_field, record_ref):
    try:
        line_num = 1
        #List of the stopwords 
        stopwords = ("For","This")
        #List of the delimiters
        delimiter_chars = ",.;:!?"
        #txt_fil Variable in which we copy the Text Column
        txt_fil = ("This This file is a test of the text_file_indexer.py program.")
        #Dictionary with "word"=>occurrences
        word_occurrences = {}
        #Split the Text into words delimited by whitespace.
        words = txt_fil.split()
        #Remove unwanted delimiter characters adjoining words.
        words1 = [ word.strip(delimiter_chars) for word in words ]
        #Remove stopwords.
        words2 = words1[:]
        for word in words1:
            if word in stopwords: 
                words2.remove(word) 
        #Count and save word occurences
        for word in words2:
            if word in word_occurrences:
                word_occurrences[word] = [ line_num + 1 ] 
            else:
                word_occurrences[word] = [ line_num ]
        #Supposedly after this we open Index Table and store the words, their occurences , and a reference for the records in which they were found
```

Comment: Do you have a link to that article you mention? I am not sure I understand what you mean by `hard coded indexing class`; also please include your code, hopefully that will clear things up ;)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste, i added the code i developed so far,when i add a claim in my database i pass it's topic field  to the function to index it

Comment: Sorry forgot the article here you go but it's in French and i quote from the article "The techniques provided by the DBMS are not satisfactory , because we can not index a memo field or a character field if it is too long. In addition, indexing a character field is valid only if the search takes place on the first characters of this field , which is rarely the case in practice" http://dominiquemaniez.developpez.com/indexauto/

Comment: OK, as I understand it (and first sentence points this out) it is a bit confusing to call this indexing, I'd call it `tagging` (meaning you have a list of relevant "tag"-words and a relation somewhere relating those list entries to the actual data; but tbh I only saw auto translation from google and it wasn't that good :D)

So when you expect that your data should be searchable freely (not only comparing complete strings or the starting of strings) then yes, `tagging approach has the potential to be faster` pretty sure. Can't comment on your code though, don't know enough python.